# Convert DOCX to PDF for mulitple folders

Tags: powershell, pdf, ms-word

Using Powershell we're able to convert Word files to PDF using the code below, but we need to do this for multiple folders.  How can we do this?

```
$wdFormatPDF = 17
$word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
$word.visible = $false
$folderpath = "C:\folder\*"
$fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes |
foreach-object `
{
 $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
 "Converting $path to pdf ..."
 $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
 $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
 $doc.close()
}
$word.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize the -Directory property of `Get-ChildItem` to get only directories of a given folder and then enumerate your code on each individual folder

```
$Folders = Get-ChildItem <Path to convert here> -Directory

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
    $wdFormatPDF = 17
    $word = New-Object -ComObject word.application
    $word.visible = $false
    $folderpath = "$($Folder.FullName)\*"
    $fileTypes = "*.docx","*doc"
    Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes |
    foreach-object `
    {
     $path =  ($_.fullname).substring(0,($_.FullName).lastindexOf("."))
     "Converting $path to pdf ..."
     $doc = $word.documents.open($_.fullname)
     $doc.saveas([ref] $path, [ref]$wdFormatPDF)
     $doc.close()
    }
    $word.Quit()
}
```

Comment: What about subfolders of the subfolder?

Comment: For the subfolders add -recurse to make the first line `$Folders = Get-ChildItem <Path to convert here> -Directory -Recurse`.

Be careful if you do this though as Recurse will go through EVERY subfolder which mean your script will convert EVERY .dox and .docx to pdf. If you want to exclude certain folders it would be more efficient to not recurse and simply put the documents into one folder.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Recursive will solve the problem easy.

```
Get-ChildItem -path $folderpath -include $fileTypes -Recursive |
```